# can anyone help me with where to place a submit button in this flutter code i dont seem to be getting it?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckBoxInListview extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckBoxInListviewState createState() => _CheckBoxInListviewState();
}

class _CheckBoxInListviewState extends State<CheckBoxInListview> {
  bool _isChecked = true;

  List<String> _texts = ["Movies", "Music", "Exercise", "Games"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Select likes to proceed with registration"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: _texts
            .map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(text),
                  value: _isChecked,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isChecked = val;
                    });
                  },
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize floatingActionButton as you want:

```
  class _CheckBoxInListviewState extends State<CheckBoxInListview> {
  bool _isChecked = true;

  List<String> _texts = ["Movies", "Music", "Exercise", "Games"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Select likes to proceed with registration"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: _texts
            .map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text(text),
                  value: _isChecked,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isChecked = val;
                    });
                  },
                ))
            .toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: RaisedButton(onPressed: null),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, put function that you need instead of 'null', you welcome